# Cannot read property \'findAll\' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

here my problem is I need to update wallet table amount field where using transaction table by using post api… here I am able to create transaction table not able to find wallet details I am not getting how to match transaction and wallet..

```
controller.js

`const create =  async function(req, res){    

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

let  err, trans, wallet ;
 let transaction_info = req.body;  
//   let recharg = recharge;   
 [err, trans] = await to(transaction.create(transaction_info,));
//   console.log('request =',res);
 if(err){
     return ReE(res, err);
    }   
    if ('amount' in transaction_info){
        var amount = {
            cid : transaction_info.cardnum,
            amount : transaction_info.amount,
            status : transaction_info.status
        } 
        wallet = await AuthService.update(amount);
        console.log('wallet_info : <<<<<< ' + JSON.stringify(wallet));
        trans.cardnum = User.cid;
        console.log('order <<<<<<' + JSON.stringify(orders));
    }
    [err, transaction] = await to (transaction.save());
    if(err) return ReE(res, err, 422);
 let transaction_json = trans.toWeb();
 return ReS(res,{trans:transaction_json}, 201);
}

 module.exports.create = create;`


  authservice.js


   `const update = async function (body) {
  let err, wallet , remainingwallet;
let wallet_inf = body;
var updated = false;
console.log('body'+ JSON.stringify(body));
[err, remainingwallet] = await to(wallet.findAll(
    {
    limit :1,
    where : {   
        cid : wallet_inf.cid=User.id,
    },

    transaction: [
        ['id','DESC']
    ]        
    }
));
if(wallet_inf.status === true){
 [err, wallet] = await to(wallet.create(wallet_inf));
 if(err) return TE(JSON.stringify(err));

 updated = true;
 [err, wallet] = await to(wallet.save());
}
else{
    TE('Please check your balance')
}
return wallet;
 }
    module.exports.update = update;
```

I am expecting to update wallet amount field using transaction fields

Comment: You haven’t defined `wallet` before using `wallet.findAll`.

Comment: sorry I didn't mention there but it is defined in code

Comment: const wallet        = require('../models').wallet;

Comment: That’s not the same variable. You have a `let err, wallet, remainingwallet;` and never define `wallet` in this scope before using `wallet.findAll`.

Comment: hey tanks man, its taking local variable..